# Github Action: build from cache in auto-label-merge-conflicts?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions, building-github-actions

In the following workflow, I want to add cache functionality so that, every time it will build from scratch. this is the workflow:

```
# This workflow will do
# a clean install of node deps
# build the source code
# run test across different versions of node

name: Conflict Check
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - staging
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - staging

jobs:
  triage:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: mschilde/auto-label-merge-conflicts@master
        with:
          CONFLICT_LABEL_NAME: 'has conflicts'
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [actions/cache](https://github.com/actions/cache) action for purposes of caching in Github Actions.

```yaml
jobs:
  triage:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Cache build files
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: ${{ PATH_TO_CACHE }}
          key:${{ runner.os }}-${{ hashFiles(<glob_pattern_for_files>) }}
      - uses: mschilde/auto-label-merge-conflicts@master
        with:
          CONFLICT_LABEL_NAME: 'has conflicts'
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

The example above assumes you want to cache your files between runs on different `refs` but your actual key declaration would depend on what you are trying to do.

For example if you are trying to cache between jobs or workflow runs on same ref:

```
key: ${{ runner.os }}-${{ github.sha }}
```